# Optional parameter in TypeORM queryBuilder

Tags: javascript, sql, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

Is it possible to use optional parameters in `createQueryBuilder`?

for example, I have this code:

```js
let users = await this.conn
  .getRepository(UserEntity)
  .createQueryBuilder("user")
  .where("user.firstName LIKE :search", { search: dto.search })
  .getMany();
```

my optional parameter is `search`, I want to launch clauses `.where` only when `dto.search` is not null, but when he is null then should skip this function(`where`) and goes to `getMany`.

Have anybody any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
let users = await this.conn.getRepository(UserEntity)
  .createQueryBuilder('user')
  .where(search !== null 
    ? 'user.firstName LIKE :search'
    : 'TRUE', { search: dto.search })
  .getMany();
```

Or another way to do without the `where TRUE` is:

```
let users = this.conn.getRepository(UserEntity)
  .createQueryBuilder('user');
users = search !== null 
  ? users.where('user.firstName LIKE :search',{ search: dto.search })
  : users
users = await users.getMany();
```

Comment: be careful with this section `search !== null`. It will not take into account situations when dto.search is undefined, or has a zero length string value.  It will likely lead to inaccurate query results.

Answer (score 5):

```
const query = this.conn
  .getRepository(UserEntity)
  .createQueryBuilder("user");

// Optionally add where condition
if(dto.search){
  query.where("user.firstName LIKE :search", { search: dto.search })
}
// run query
let users = await query.getMany();
```

Do be mindful of falsy values that would trip up the if statement.